How to write a performance-portable daxpy?
Problem
A daxpy is the computation y = y + alpha * x for vectors x, y and scalar alpha. This is limited by RAM-CPU bandwidth if x, y do not fit in cache. On my system, I consistently get only 23 GB/s, whereas the peak bandwidth is 51 GB/s. That is quite a large gap, so I would like to optimise this.
Constraints
I do not mind doing some tests like FFTW or Atlas to get machine-specific parameters, but it should be systematic enough that the resulting program is performance-portable.
Some investigation
To reproduce
gcc -O3 -mavx2 -mfma daxpy.c -o daxpy
./daxpy 1000 1

When computing the same result many times, we get 49 GB/s, which is close to the peak of 51. To reproduce:
gcc -O3 -mavx2 -mfma daxpy.c -o daxpy
./daxpy 1000 100

GCC version is 12.2.0, I have inspected the assembly, and it does not seem to exchange the loops or do something else to improve locality (edit: maybe someone wants to check this, I cannot reproduce the issue with clang and I am not that good at reading assembly).
Profiling shows a L1D miss reduction from 17% to 12%, so I suspect the hardware prefetcher needs many iterations before figuring out the right parameters.
I tried the following
void daxpy(size_t n, double *x, double *y, double alpha, size_t ahead, size_t unroll)
{
    size_t ii = 0;
    for (; ii + unroll <= n; ii += unroll) {
        for (int u = 0; u < unroll; u += 8) {
            _mm_prefetch(x + ii + ahead + u, _MM_HINT_T2);
            _mm_prefetch(y + ii + ahead + u, _MM_HINT_T2);
        }
        for (size_t i = ii; i < ii + unroll; i++) {
            y[i] = alpha * x[i] + y[i];
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = ii; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = alpha * x[i] + y[i];
    }
}

but was not able to find proper parameters.
Test System
I have a zen2 CPU (Ryzen 4600H), two 4 GB RAM sticks running at 3200 MHz. No weird NUMA structure according to hwloc.
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Machine (7303MB total)                                                                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                                                                           │
│ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  ├┤╶─┬─────┼┤╶───────┬──────────────────────┐    │
│ │ Package L#0                                                                                          │      │2.0       2.0  │ PCI 01:00.0          │    │
│ │                                                                                                      │      │               │                      │    │
│ │ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │      │               │ ┌──────────────────┐ │    │
│ │ │ NUMANode L#0 P#0 (7303MB)                                                                        │ │      │               │ │ CoProc opencl0d0 │ │    │
│ │ └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │      │               │ │                  │ │    │
│ │                                                                                                      │      │               │ │ 14 compute units │ │    │
│ │ ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │      │               │ │                  │ │    │
│ │ │ L3 (4096KB)                                   │  │ L3 (4096KB)                                   │ │      │               │ │ 3896 MB          │ │    │
│ │ └───────────────────────────────────────────────┘  └───────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │      │               │ └──────────────────┘ │    │
│ │                                                                                                      │      │               └──────────────────────┘    │
│ │ ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐ │      │                                           │
│ │ │ L2 (512KB)  │  │ L2 (512KB)  │  │ L2 (512KB)  │  │ L2 (512KB)  │  │ L2 (512KB)  │  │ L2 (512KB)  │ │      ├─────┼┤╶───────┬───────────────────┐       │
│ │ └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘ │      │3.9       3.9  │ PCI 02:00.0       │       │
│ │                                                                                                      │      │               │                   │       │
│ │ ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐ │      │               │ ┌───────────────┐ │       │
│ │ │ L1d (32KB)  │  │ L1d (32KB)  │  │ L1d (32KB)  │  │ L1d (32KB)  │  │ L1d (32KB)  │  │ L1d (32KB)  │ │      │               │ │ Block nvme0n1 │ │       │
│ │ └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘ │      │               │ │               │ │       │
│ │                                                                                                      │      │               │ │ 476 GB        │ │       │
│ │ ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐ │      │               │ └───────────────┘ │       │
│ │ │ L1i (32KB)  │  │ L1i (32KB)  │  │ L1i (32KB)  │  │ L1i (32KB)  │  │ L1i (32KB)  │  │ L1i (32KB)  │ │      │               └───────────────────┘       │
│ │ └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘ │      │                                           │
│ │                                                                                                      │      ├─────┼┤╶───────┬──────────────┐            │
│ │ ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐ │      │0.2       0.2  │ PCI 03:00.0  │            │
│ │ │ Core L#0    │  │ Core L#1    │  │ Core L#2    │  │ Core L#3    │  │ Core L#4    │  │ Core L#5    │ │      │               │              │            │
│ │ │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │ │      │               │ ┌──────────┐ │            │
│ │ │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │      │               │ │ Net eno1 │ │            │
│ │ │ │ PU L#0  │ │  │ │ PU L#2  │ │  │ │ PU L#4  │ │  │ │ PU L#6  │ │  │ │ PU L#8  │ │  │ │ PU L#10 │ │ │      │               │ └──────────┘ │            │
│ │ │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │ │      │               └──────────────┘            │
│ │ │ │   P#0   │ │  │ │   P#2   │ │  │ │   P#4   │ │  │ │   P#6   │ │  │ │   P#8   │ │  │ │  P#10   │ │ │      │                                           │
│ │ │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │ │      ├─────┼┤╶───────┬────────────────┐          │
│ │ │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │      │0.2       0.2  │ PCI 04:00.0    │          │
│ │ │ │ PU L#1  │ │  │ │ PU L#3  │ │  │ │ PU L#5  │ │  │ │ PU L#7  │ │  │ │ PU L#9  │ │  │ │ PU L#11 │ │ │      │               │                │          │
│ │ │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │  │ │         │ │ │      │               │ ┌────────────┐ │          │
│ │ │ │   P#1   │ │  │ │   P#3   │ │  │ │   P#5   │ │  │ │   P#7   │ │  │ │   P#9   │ │  │ │  P#11   │ │ │      │               │ │ Net wlp4s0 │ │          │
│ │ │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │ │      │               │ └────────────┘ │          │
│ │ └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘ │      │               └────────────────┘          │
│ └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘      │                                           │
│                                                                                                               ├─────┼┤╶───────┬─────────────┐             │
│                                                                                                               │32        32   │ PCI 05:00.0 │             │
│                                                                                                               │               └─────────────┘             │
│                                                                                                               │                                           │
│                                                                                                               └─────┼┤╶───────┬───────────────────────┐   │
│                                                                                                                32        32   │ 2 x { PCI 06:00.0-1 } ├─┐ │
│                                                                                                                               └─┬─────────────────────┘ │ │
│                                                                                                                                 └───────────────────────┘ │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


daxpy.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

double wtime(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)(tv.tv_usec / 1e6 + tv.tv_sec);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <N> <ITER>\n"
               "\tN:     size of vector in MB\n" 
               "\tITER:  number of times to repeat experiment\n",
               argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t n = 1e6 * atoi(argv[1]) / sizeof(double);
    int iter = atoi(argv[2]);

    size_t size = (n * sizeof(double) + 63) / 64 * 64;
    double *x = aligned_alloc(64, size);
    double *y = aligned_alloc(64, size);

    madvise(x, size, MADV_SEQUENTIAL);
    madvise(y, size, MADV_SEQUENTIAL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0;
        y[i] = 1.0;
    }

    double alpha = 3.0;

    int pid= getpid();
    int cpid = fork();


    if( cpid == 0)
    {
        char buf[50];
        sprintf(buf, "perf stat -d -d -p %d", pid);
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", buf, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        setpgid(cpid, 0);
    
        double tik = wtime();

        for (int t = 0; t < iter; t++) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                y[i] = alpha * x[i] + y[i];
            }
        }

        kill(-cpid, SIGINT);
        double tok = wtime();
        double gb = 3.0 * n * sizeof(double) * iter / 1e9;
        fprintf(stderr, "BW: %lf GB/s\n", gb / (tok - tik));
    }

    free(x);
    free(y);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


Your title mentions portable.  What do you mean by that?  What range of hardware do you want to port to?

@JonathanLeffler I would like a daxpy (such as the one I tried in investigation) that is sufficiently parameterised that it can run fast on all commodity desktop computers / servers. Let's say x86 if it matters, but I think it is mostly about prefetching and not any specific instruction set.

What about using BLAS? It has daxpy. The library has optimized versions for many platforms/architectures. Either just use the lib or get the source as a guide.

What about openmp, Cuda, or opencl?

@CraigEstey With both BLIS and OpenBLAS, it is consistently 23 GB/s. So maybe GCC does do some locality optimisation I am missing. I do not have a GPU, so no point in cuda or OpenCL . OpenMP shows the same behaviour.
